# Notepad shows Unicode character as file is ANSI?

Tags: c++, c, linux, notepad++

I have created one file that contains (degree celcius character) and other character that required more then one byte. In Notepad++ it shows encode ANSI and as it is ANSI then why Notepad shows that multibyte character ?

Any idea ?

Thanks,
Neel

Comment: Did you mean `degree` or `degree Celcius`? There is a difference; the former can be displayed in ANSI, while the latter can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't save it in UNICODE! Notepad will save it in ANSI as long as the codepage supports the characters involved.

To save in UNICODE you must select that from the drop-down list when saving a file.

Comment: @NeelPatel beside every answer to your question there is a green check mark. Just click that for the answer that best helped you. See this on how it works http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: But how Notepad shows that character although it is in ANSI format ?